# How to create TF Dataset from GeoTiff files using custom map() function

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, geotiff, rasterio

I'm trying to create a TensorFlow Dataset from multichannel tiff files. The `tfio.experimental.image.decode_tiff(image)` from TensorFlow I/O works for 4 channels only so I tried to read it first into numpy using in this case `rasterio` and then convert it to TF like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import rasterio as rio

@tf.compat.v2.autograph.experimental.do_not_convert
def parse_image(img_path: str) -> dict:
    
    src = rio.open(img_path)
    image_numpy = src.read()
    image = tf.convert_to_tensor(image_numpy, dtype=tf.float32)

    return {'image': image}

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files("multipage_tiff_example.tif", seed=50)
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(parse_image)
```

Unfortunately, I can't get over this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-77-8308896524b1> in <module>
     11 
     12 train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files("multipage_tiff_example.tif", seed=50)
---> 13 train_dataset = train_dataset.map(parse_image)

[...]

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/proj1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rasterio/__init__.py in open(fp, mode, driver, width, height, count, crs, transform, dtype, nodata, sharing, **kwargs)
    156     if not isinstance(fp, string_types):
    157         if not (hasattr(fp, 'read') or hasattr(fp, 'write') or isinstance(fp, Path)):
--> 158             raise TypeError("invalid path or file: {0!r}".format(fp))
    159     if mode and not isinstance(mode, string_types):
    160         raise TypeError("invalid mode: {0!r}".format(mode))

TypeError: invalid path or file: <tf.Tensor 'args_0:0' shape=() dtype=string>
```

The exemplary tif file is here: http://www.nightprogrammer.org/wp-uploads/2013/02/multipage_tiff_example.tif

```
tf.__version__: 2.5.0-rc3
rio.__version__: 1.1.8
```

I did lots of cross-checks. For example:

- Loading a file via rasterio to numpy works
- parse() function with standard jpg and tf.io inside works:

```
    image = tf.io.read_file(img_path)
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)
```

- same error occurs when I pass to Dataset.list_files() the whole dir with files using proper dir+files patterns

The problem "**invalid path or file**" is raised by rasterio but I feel that it might be related/caused by TF mechanisms.

Could You please advise how to make it work?

Comment: @ Lukiz I am facing same error in reading multi-band images. Would you please share how you solved this problem?

Comment: @rayan Unfortunately I didn't. I have put this project on-hold since then.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but it show up when I faced the same problem. In my case I'm trying to work with images with 6 channels (256, 256, 6).

I figured out how to solve this problem in tensorflow `1.14`, but I believe that it can be used in tensorflow v2 (I don't have this version in my machine).

You can use the `tf.py_function` to wrap the `parse_image` function:

```py
# TF 1.14 needs to enable eager execution (default in TF 2)
tf.enable_eager_execution()

# df_img_train['images_path'] holds the images path

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(df_img_train['images_path'])
ds = ds.map(lambda x: tf.py_function(parse_image, [x], [tf.float32])).batch(8)
```

Then you can adjust the `parse_image` function to read the string in the Tensor:

```py
def parse_image(img_path: str):
    # Cast the Tensor to numpy and decode the string
    img_path = img_path.numpy().decode('utf-8')

    with rasterio.open(img_path) as src:
        img = src.read()
        # Channels last
        img = np.moveaxis(img, 0, 2)

    return img
```

Note that this implementation returns an numpy array that will be casted to `tf.float32` (the third parameter in `tf.py_function`). Now its possible to iterate over your dataset:

```
for img in ds:
    print(img[0].shape)

# Output: (8, 256, 256, 6)
```

I noticed that you want to return a dictionary, but this code may serves you as well.